# DeleteWebFolder SkyDrive .Net API Client using C#

Tags: c#, onedrive

This is my code and I'm confused what to write in `foreach` loop. Please help me
any advice will be helpful

```
SkyDriveServiceClient svcClient = new SkyDriveServiceClient();
svcClient.LogOn( "username", "*********" );
WebFolderInfo[] rootwebFI = svcClient.ListRootWebFolders();
foreach(WebFolderInfo deleteWebFI in rootwebFI)
{

}
```

Comment: http://imageripper.googlecode.com/svn-history/r142/trunk/ImgRipper/Cloud.cs look at this code, there is some removing/adding folders

Comment: Ok I am able to delete File/Folder but I am not able to delete a particular File/Folder. I don't know how give path or file name to delete.